# Oil extraction from lemon

Tags: oil, lemon

Recently I have taken to natural aromas and colours. Does anyone have any idea on best method and equipment for extraction of oil from lemon rind?

Comment: Are you wanting to do this with home (kitchen?) tools, or considering investing in professional level equipment?

Comment: You could read answer and comments to a question asking about mint oil, menthol.

Comment: You could read answer and comments to a question asking about mint oil, menthol.

Comment: You could read answer and comments to a question asking about mint oil, menthol.

Comment: Exploring right now with kitchen equipment and would like to know about professional level extracting equipment. Thank you for the information Alchimista.

Answer (score 2):

I know that probably this is not what you want, but the simplest way to get lemon flavored oil is by infusion with a neutral oil. Non-polar dissolve non-polar, so this will do the extraction. But you won't be able to separate the pure lemon oil.

Now, if you really want pure oil you probably have to go for distillation. For that, you will need a distill like [this](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/b5/a0/89/b5a089daab49ea1384ab7bfb89da3a6f.jpg) or [that](http://www.modernroots.org/uploads/1/6/5/6/16560502/9528787_orig.jpg).

Some people make it, but you can find either version on Amazon (which is safer). Once you have that, it is not that hard. There are many video tutorials like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IC0qYhQ2XNg) or [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bGlMDt1cT_4) for the pressure pan setting.

It is important to keep in mind that any essential oil extraction has an extremely small yield. As you can see from the video, you need a huge amount of initial material to even be able to see the oil layer floating above the liquid phase.

Comment: + 1 for a nicely explained answer. One other thought to keep in mind when going the distillation route: many essential oils have some toxicity so it is important to do research before using them indiscriminately. And they don't taste exactly like the original either. So again, infusion is probably the better choice for most applications.

Comment: Appreciate the info greedyscholars and rumtscho. I wanted to use it in chocolate.